# In javascript, what's the most efficient way to I turn tags into links?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Let's say I have some HTML:

```
Hello, I'm a #robot and this is my #home.
```

How can I turn this into:

```
Hello, I'm a <a href="blah.com/robot" class="tag">#robot</a> and this is my <a href="blah.com/home" class="tag">#home</a>
```

I've tried using JQuery by iterating over each word and doing a find/replace, but it was very expensive. What's a better way to do it?

Comment: Clue: regexp could be a solution!

Comment: Requires regex. I recently did something but I'm particularly interested in sharing my code. What project are you working on?

Comment: Where is the text coming from? From a server? And why is it in that format?

Comment: @JacksonGariety Requires is a strong word :) This is quite a simple case that could be parsed and replaced manually. For a regex beginner, that could be even easier. Although, op wouldn't be asking then :)

Comment: What needs to be done is grab all the text nodes on the page and use regex to filter out the parts that contain hashtags. Then use a .replace() javascript to add in the anchor tags around.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Below is the code you can use to replace hash signs with a link. Feel free to experiment with it, and comment any questions you may have :)

```
var text = "Hello, I'm a #robot and this is my #home.";

alert(text.replace(/#([a-z0-9]+)/gi, '<a href="blah.com/$1">#$1</a>'));

// It alerts the following "Hello, I'm a <a href="blah.com/robot">#robot</a> and this is my <a href="blah.com/home">#home</a>."
```

Answer (score -2):

jQuery is not intended for pure text manipulation. I guess the best alternative here would be do such changes server-side. If not possible, a simple find/replace would do the trick, in such case jQuery could be used just to iterate over some elements that contains this HTML, making its access easier.

HTH